# SQL MIN(COUNT) does not seem to be working properly?

Tags: sql, count, mariadb, min, groupwise-maximum

First, I generated a table from the following query:

```
select su.supplier_zip, sp.shop_zip, COUNT(p.ptypes) 
from supplier su 
inner join parts p on su.sid=p.sid 
inner join sales s on p.parts_pid=s.pid 
inner join shop sp on s.shop_id=sp.shop_id 
group by sp.shop_zip, su.supplier_zip 
order by su.supplier_zip;

+--------------+----------+-----------------+
| supplier_zip | shop_zip | COUNT(p.ptypes) |
+--------------+----------+-----------------+
|         7733 |    85254 |               6 |
|         7733 |    33603 |               2 |
|         7733 |    92821 |               7 |
|         7733 |    95070 |               2 |
|         7733 |    94010 |               5 |
|         7733 |    68154 |               6 |
|         7733 |    45277 |               4 |
|         7733 |    94568 |               3 |
|         7733 |    55401 |               3 |
|         7733 |    85308 |               5 |
|         7733 |    85226 |               6 |
|         7733 |    11021 |               3 |
|         7733 |    35243 |               5 |
|         7733 |     7764 |               3 |
|         7733 |    26505 |               1 |
|        26505 |    85226 |               6 |
|        26505 |    55401 |               4 |
|        26505 |    92821 |               5 |
|        26505 |    45277 |               1 |
|        26505 |    26505 |               6 |
|        26505 |    94568 |               4 |
|        26505 |    85254 |               6 |
...
```

and I am trying to get the MIN of the COUNTS listed. So I made it a select within a select and I end up getting:

```
+-------------+---------+-----------+
| supplierzip | shopzip | MIN(type) |
+-------------+---------+-----------+
|        7733 |   55401 |         1 |
|       26505 |   85308 |         1 |
|       33603 |   94568 |         3 |
|       45277 |   33603 |         1 |
|       55401 |   55401 |         1 |
|       60601 |   85254 |         3 |
|       68154 |   94568 |         2 |
|       85226 |   85226 |         6 |
|       92821 |   85226 |         5 |
|       94568 |   45277 |         2 |
+-------------+---------+-----------+
```

using the query:

```
select supplierzip, shopzip, MIN(type) 
from (
select su.supplier_zip as supplierzip, sp.shop_zip as shopzip, COUNT(p.ptypes) as type 
from supplier su 
inner join parts p on su.sid=p.sid 
inner join sales s on p.parts_pid=s.pid 
inner join shop sp on s.shop_id=sp.shop_id 
group by sp.shop_zip, su.supplier_zip 
order by su.supplier_zip)a 
group by supplierzip;
```

The results are not right. because when you look at it for supplierzip-7733, the shopzip should be 26505 with the MIN(num) of 1. But that is not the answer that I am getting.

Comment: your query should throw an error. shopzip is not in group by

Comment: When you add shopzip to the group by it will list out all the different types, but I only wanted the min

Comment: yes, but if you do that, you don't get the result you say you get. How do you get that result?

Comment: Isn't there a way to do it so that when you just get the min of each supplierzip and you would get the corresponding shopzip?

Comment: sure there is. I want to know, how you reached your current result, so we can work on it

Comment: Perhaps this MariaDB instance is **not** using ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY and this (poor) practice leads to all sorts of results that don't make sense. Without proper grouping the results are an **approximation**

Comment: Follow the tag [groupwise-maximum]

Answer (score 0):

Use a windowed minimum instead:

```
SELECT
    supplierzip
  , shopzip
  , MIN( type ) over(partition by supplierzip)
FROM (
    SELECT
        su.supplier_zip   AS supplierzip
      , sp.shop_zip       AS shopzip
      , COUNT( p.ptypes ) AS type
    FROM supplier su
    INNER JOIN parts p ON su.sid = p.sid
    INNER JOIN sales s ON p.parts_pid = s.pid
    INNER JOIN shop sp ON s.shop_id = sp.shop_id
    GROUP BY
        su.supplier_zip 
      , sp.shop_zip
    ) a
ORDER BY
    supplierzip
  , shopzip
```

Note there is no reason to use order by in the subquery.

Please note that ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is now the default behaviour for both MariaDB and MySQL and frankly is always should have been (in my view). see [GROUP BY](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/group-by/).

Take for example the results you display in the question:

```
+-------------+---------+-----------+
| supplierzip | shopzip | MIN(type) |
+-------------+---------+-----------+
|        7733 |   55401 |         1 |
```

which is derived from:

```
| supplier_zip | shop_zip | COUNT(p.ptypes) |
+--------------+----------+-----------------+
|         7733 |    85254 |               6 |
|         7733 |    33603 |               2 |
|         7733 |    92821 |               7 |
|         7733 |    95070 |               2 |
|         7733 |    94010 |               5 |
|         7733 |    68154 |               6 |
|         7733 |    45277 |               4 |
|         7733 |    94568 |               3 |
|         7733 |    55401 |               3 |  <<== why is 55401 chosen???
|         7733 |    85308 |               5 |
|         7733 |    85226 |               6 |
|         7733 |    11021 |               3 |
|         7733 |    35243 |               5 |
|         7733 |     7764 |               3 |
|         7733 |    26505 |               1 |
```

but there is no apparent logic for the choice of shopzip 55401. This (looks like) the "approximation" used when ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is not on.